# Where i must get Ajax Helper or how to create it to use @AjaxExtensions.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-6.0

I want to use @AjaxExtensions.ActionLink(AjaxHelper, String, String, String, RouteValueDictionary, AjaxOptions) in cshtml file (ASP.Net 6 MVC).

```
@model List<Shift>
@using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

@{
    AjaxOptions deleteOptions = new AjaxOptions()
            {
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "table"
            };
}

        @foreach (Shift shift in Model)
        {<td>
@AjaxExtensions.ActionLink( ???,"Delete", "DeleteShift", "MainDoctor", new{id=shift.Id}, deleteOptions)
</td>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-ajax-ajaxextensions-actionlink(system-web-mvc-ajaxhelper-system-string-system-string-system-string-system-web-routing-routevaluedictionary-system-web-mvc-ajax-ajaxoptions)) said, `AjaxExtensions.ActionLink` is only applies to ASP.NET MVC 5.2, and the correct usage should be:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteShift", "MainDoctor", new { id = shift.Id }, deleteOptions)
```

In ASP.NET 6, you need use an alternative way like below:

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#table" data-ajax-url="@Url.Action("DeleteShift", "MainDoctor", new { id = shift.Id})">Delete</a>
```

A simple working demo you could follow:

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
}
```

View(`Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@model Test
<div id="table">
    @Model.Id
    <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#table" data-ajax-url="@Url.Action("DeleteShift", "MainDoctor", new { id = 1 })">Delete</a>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" integrity="sha256-v2nySZafnswY87um3ymbg7p9f766IQspC5oqaqZVX2c=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
}
```

Controller:

```
public class MainDoctorController:Controller
{
    public IActionResult DeleteShift(int id)
    {
        var model = new Test()
        {
            Id = "bb"
        };
        return PartialView("/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", model);
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var model = new Test()
        {
            Id = "aaa"
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I did so, but I thought it was possible somehow through the helper method

Comment: Hi @Denis, of course it may be possible to custom a helper to do, but I think `data-xxx` attribute is clear enough.